# How to use getApplication of and Activity class to store my of Value in non Activity class in the ActivityClass

Tags: android

I have develop an app, in which i have an created a global Activity class which stores all my list and boolean varaiable which can be use in any Activity class and also in non activity class. but when i want to use the `getApplication()` in my non activity class it gives me error .

the sample code
This is my Application which has all the list and boolean variables to be used

```
public class MyApplicationData extends Application
{
    public  String USER_ID = "";
        public  double user_latitude;
        public  double user_logitude;

        // for password
        public  boolean remember_password = false;
        public ArrayList<Integer>value= new ArrayList<Integer>();
}
```

I have Another class which is  non Activity where i want to use my list to save some data
For your reference here is sample code

```
public class Test
{    
    public MyApplicationData myApplicationData;
    GetApplication getApplicationData ;
    @Override
    public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length) throws SAXException 
    {
        super.characters(ch, start, length);
        String data = new String(ch,start,length);
        if(in_userid)
        {
            XMLData.user_info_map.put("userid",data);
            Log.v("--: PARSED DATA :-- MAP"+i, "userid = "+data);
        }
        if(in_firstname)
            {
            XMLData.user_info_map.put("firstname",data);
            Log.v("--: PARSED DATA :-- MAP"+i, "firstname = "+data);

        }
     } 
 }
```

I have class which extends `Activity`

```
public class GetApplication extends Activity
{
  public MyApplicationData getTheApplication()
  {

      return (MyApplicationData)getApplication();
  }
}
```

I am stuck here can any one help how to store values using Application you help will be highly obliged

Answer (score 0):

You could try to store the value in a preferences & call it anywhere as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by a "global" Activity class (an Activity class typically represents a UI view), but if you're looking to persist data for access by multiple activities, something like a SharedPreferences might work for you:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref

If you mean how to access the application context, and store stuff in the application. This SO answer seems to accomplish what you want:

[How to declare global variables in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/708012/android-how-to-declare-global-variables)